# Dynamically adding Thumbnail in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

i am trying to add a thumbnail dynamically to my relative layout. This is code here

```
public void showViewOfReceipt(String fileName)
         {
             byte[] imageData = null;

             try
             {

             final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 64;

             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
             Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

             Float width = new Float(imageBitmap.getWidth());
             Float height = new Float(imageBitmap.getHeight());
             Float ratio = width/height;
             imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, (int)(THUMBNAIL_SIZE * ratio), THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
             imageData = baos.toByteArray();
             ImageView image = new ImageView(this); 

             image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
             RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.expLayout5);
             layout.addView(image); 
             }
             catch(Exception ex) {
             } 
         }
```

It never shows anything

Regards

Comment: You'd better see if there is exception thrown within your code. It will tell you more about the error when creating the `Bitmap` or `FileInputStream` etc.

Comment: Writing EMPTY Catch block is bad practise,Always put atleast a log to put in there.

Comment: can u put the whole code here?

Comment: What you are passing as the fileName for this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Change your relative layout to Linear Layout
2- Use this code below to get the bitmap image

```
Uri photoUri = data.getData();
                     String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null); 
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                        {
                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            cursor.close();
                            Bitmap imageReturned = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                            showImageInLayout(imageReturned);
```

Then define a function `showImageInLayout(Bitmap imageReturned)`

```
public void showViewOfReceiptInLayout(Bitmap imageBitmap)
         {
             byte[] imageData = null;
                 imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, yourWidth, yourHeight, false);
                 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                 imageData = baos.toByteArray();
                 ImageView image = new ImageView(this); 
                 image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                 layout.addView(image);

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your following line of code,

```
catch(Exception ex) 
{
}
```

to,

```
catch(Exception ex) 
{
      e.printStack();
}
```

So, you will get error , if any.

Comment: Sorry it says file not found. content://media/external/images/media/1 is the path of file that emulator is sending me

Answer (score 0):

Comment code line:

//image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Comment: have removed it, no effect. Sorry that was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Please update the Question with the error or exception log code so we can help you properly.

And as per Altaaf answer its an error in the fileName. So Please check it or give the code what you pass in it.

Thanks.